# "apt-get upgrade" fails with "/usr/bin/dpkg: Syntax error: newline unexpected"

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg

I am using Ubuntu 19.04. The problem is when I want to upgrade and run `sudo apt-get upgrade` command. But it is failing.

It is showing:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
/usr/bin/dpkg: 2: /usr/bin/dpkg: Syntax error: newline unexpected
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I can't install any software without upgrading my system.